# Python code for Wallis equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was asked to write a Python code for Wallis's equation, I worte the following code but the output comes out as 0.0 at all times and I don't know why or what causes the output to be 0.0.
I'm also using 3.x version.

```
n = 1000 # The number of terms to compute
pi = 0.0

for i in range(n):
  denom1 = i * 2 + 1
  denom2 = i * 2 - 1
  pi = pi * (i * 4.0)/(denom1 * denom2)
print(pi)
```

Comment: `pi` starts with a value of 0. Multiplying anything by 0 results in 0, so `pi` will always be 0.

Comment: Also note that your range starts with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to compute pi, your formula is not correct (for example, what happens when i=0?)

Here's an implementation that works:

```
n = 1000 # The number of terms to compute
halfpi = 1.0

for i in range(1, n):
  numer = i * 2
  denom = i * 2 - 1
  halfpi = halfpi * (numer * numer) / (denom * (denom + 2))
print(2 * halfpi)
```

Comment: I understand. I see my mistake and I tried running your code and it worked however I don't understand why it is half pi and not just pi?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical error:
pi = 0.0
and then you multiply the variable pi * (i*4.0)/(denom1 * denom2)
so you are basically multiplying your equation by 0

Comment: Right, I got a bit confused,

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your implementation.  We don't give homework answers here, but I can help you find the right questions.
(1) A running sum starts at 0; a running *product* starts at 1.  This is the main reason you keep getting 0.
(2) Your loop bounds are incorrect; verify them carefully.
(3) Your equation is wrong in one respect.

However, I *can* give you a useful debugging technique: when you have a sick patient, ask where it hurts: print out intermediate values.  In this case, try putting the following lines at the bottom of your loop:

```
factor = i * 4.0 / (denom1 * denom2)
print i, denom1, denom2, factor
```